# jQuery(...).kendoGrid is not a function

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a Kendo Grid but I keep getting the same error, saying that the kendoGrid is not a function:

[image]

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js">
    window.rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<h1>Upload index</h1>


<div>
    <h4>Upload file</h4>
    <form asp-controller="Upload" asp-action="Upload"
          enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload</button>
    </form>

    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)');
        });
        </script>
    }


</div>


<div class="clearfix">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>()
        .Name("notificationGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.OPERATOR_OBJECTID).Title("ID").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.SETTLEMENT_CODE).Title("settlement code").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.TECHNOLOGY_CODE).Title("tech code").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE).Title("upload").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE).Title("download").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DATA_CATEGORY_QOS_CODE).Title("data category").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.SHAPE).Title("shape").Width("100px");
            //columns.Bound(c => c.Message).Title("message").Width("100px");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Upload_Read", "Upload"))
            )
    )

</div>
```

I made sure not to have the jQuery script twice, so here's my _Layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - M20_AEK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">M20_AEK</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="CustomerType" asp-action="LoadCustomerType">Customer Type</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="DataCategory" asp-action="LoadDataCategory">Data Category</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Upload" asp-action="Index">Upload</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - M20_AEK - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(json_read.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

I tried placing the Kendo and jQuery scripts in _Layout and that didn't help. I tried different formats for the columns and column menu and fields for the Kendo grid, but it still throws the same error.
What could the issue be?

Comment: If you move all of your `<script>` tags from the end to earlier (i.e. in the head) does the problem go away?

Comment: Can you load the Jquery script in the top section of your layout

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js">
    window.rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>` This strikes me as weird - having `src` and code inside the tag also. Plus you appear to be loading two copies of jquery (since you also have `<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`).

Comment: I removed the link from the script tag 
`<script>    window.rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';</script>`
and it shows the grid now. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it correct? @mjwills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js">
    window.rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")'; </script>
```

does not look valid (you normally have `src` or code inside the tag - not both). I'd suggest removing the `src`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If you are using jQuery Office, any version, look for the plugins file attached to your project which contains jQuery code and delete  the next line completely:

```
( !function(e,t){"use strict";"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=e.document?t(e,!0): )
```

to the end of the line

```
{return C.$===k&&(C.$=Jt),e&&C.jQuery===k&&(C.jQuery=Qt),k},e||(C.jQuery=C.$=k), k});
```

Because it will be duplicated in jQuery.js file. This is what is causing the error:

[image]